# Insert File stream to std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, filestream, destructor

I'm trying to implement std::map (actually std::pair) with file streams. Because standart c++ file streams (ifstreams ofstream, and fstream) aren't copyable, choice fell on the **FILE** from **stdio**.
This is simplest class wrapper:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class FileWriter
{
public:
    FileWriter(const char* fileName)  
    {
        _fs = fopen(fileName, "w");
    }
    ~FileWriter() 
    { 
        fclose(_fs); 
    }

private:
    FILE* _fs;
};
```

Let's trying to use this class as template parameter in std::map:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, FileWriter> a{ { 1, FileWriter("fl.fl") } };
}
```

It compiles well, but I get a runtime error - memory dump. Debugger shows, that the destructor ~FileWriter() performed **twice**. Why this happened and how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the copy constructor just copied the `FILE*` and a temporary object was created while inserting the object into the `std::map<...>`. As a result, the `FILE*` passed in got `fclose()`d and you got undefined behavior when you tried to access the `FILE*`.

In C++11 it is possible to `emplace()` streams into a map:

```
std::map<int, std::ofstream> streams;
streams.emplace(42, std::ofstream("hello, world"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my compiler - gcc 4.7, doesn't support emplace() for std::map, and move assignment operator for streams.

Comment: gcc-4.8. allows compile-error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)’

Comment: @gorill: You might not need assignment if you can use `swap`: `m[10].swap(mystream)`

Comment: @gorill: are you compiling with `-std=c++11`? You need move support to move streams. I'm not sure when libstdc++ implemented moving of streams, though.

Comment: @ Dietmar Kühl, yes, I'm compile with c++11 support

Answer (score 1):

You created your map with a temporary, which will be copied into the map at the position where it is needed. Since you didn't provide a copy constructor, the default is used, which will simply copy `_fs`.  The destructor of the temporary is called, closing the file. Then, when the map is destroyed, the destructor will be called again on the copy which was placed in the map.

You need to provide your own copy constructor with appropriate semantics. But what should be the semantics? iostreams are not copyable for a reason. You could make your class move only, but then you're in the exact same situation as the iostreams, as they too are move-only.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Answer (score 1):

> Because standart c++ file streams (ifstreams ofstream, and fstream) aren't copyable`

Yes, because **it makes no sense to copy streams**.

Streams are not containers; they are *flows of data*.

Don't try to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

The FileWriter class is constructed then copied into the map (copy constructed).  That is why the destructor is called twice.